Identify an episode of Stargate SG-1 with Ewok-like creatures
I remember seeing a clip of Stargate where it had the SG-1 team meeting oversized Ewok like creatures but bigger.  Does anyone know the episode the episode and the alien involved?

These were supposed to be the "Furlings"...

Little is known about them, except that they were a member of the "Alliance of Four Great Races", along with the Alterans, Asgard, and Nox. However, occasional artifacts attributed to the Furlings have been identified. Furling writing has also been seen on Heliopolis along with the writings of the other great races. (SG1: "The Torment of Tantalus", "The Fifth Race")
The writers have stated that although we have seen Furling technology and the Furling legacy, no actual Furling has ever appeared on the show.
Source

BUT
but their actual appearance was in the 200th "joke" show and so this is not considered canon as they appeared in the in-show TV series "Wormhole X-Treme" (dont ask..it's complicated!)




